# ajax success callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this JavaScript which works fine up to the `$.ajax({`. Then it just hangs on the loader and nothing happens.

```
$(function() {
$('.com_submit').click(function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
    var perma_id = $("#perma_id").val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&user_id='+ user_id + '&perma_id=' + perma_id;
    if(comment=='') {
        alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    }
    else {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "commentajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
        alert('This works');
                $("ol#update").append(html);
                $("ol#update li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}); 
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a successful response from the server?

Comment: At the moment I can't get anything other than "Loading Comment" and then nothing happens

Comment: Before you concern yourself with your success callback, make sure the server is sending you a response that represents success.  You might also handle the error callback to see what really happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&user_id='+ user_id + '&perma_id=' + perma_id;
```

with:

```
var dataString = { comment: comment, user_id: user_id, perma_id: perma_id };
```

in order to ensure that the parameters that you are sending to the server are properly encoded. Also make sure that the `commentajax.php` script that you are calling works fine and it doesn't throw some error in which case the success handler won't be executed and the loader indicator won't be hidden. Actually the best way to hide the loading indicator is to use the `complete` event, not the `success`. The `complete` event is triggered even in the case of an exception.

Also use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to see what exactly happens under the covers. It will allow you to see the actual AJAX request and what does the the server respond. It will also tell you if you have javascript errors and so on: you know, the kinda useful stuff when you are doing javascript enabled web development.

Comment: +1... Firebug or similar tools are essential to diagnose these things.

Comment: I tried using your `dataString` and still getting the same thing. `commentajax.php` is fine as when i run the file alone it works and inserts in to the database obviously without any data though.

Comment: @JackWillmor, OK, so what do you see in your javascript debugging tool? Is the server side script executed? Does it succeed? When you call it alone you are not sending any data so obviously you are not running it in the same conditions as the AJAX call. Really, you are like a blind man if you don't use a javascript debugging tool. Nobody can help you.